# Extract field of struct array to new array

Tags: matlab, vector, struct

I have a struct, which has 2 fields: `time` and `pose`. I have multiple instances of this struct composed in an array, so an example of this is:

```
poses(1)
    -time = 1
    -pose = (doesn't Matter)
poses(2)
    -time = 2
    -pose = (doesn't Matter)
poses(3)
    -time = 3
    -pose = (doesn't Matter)
...
```

Now when I print this:

```
 poses.time
```

I get this:

```
ans =
      1
ans =
      2
ans =
      3
```

How can I take that output and put it into a vector?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
timevec=[poses.time];
```

tricky matlab, I know I know, you'll just have to remember this one if you're working with structs ;)

Comment: What about string values ? if poses.time is ans="1" ans="2" ans="3", timevec=[poses.time] would give "123". Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @zml `"123"` is already an array, try indexing it and see for yourself. If you want them really separate, you'll need a cell array: `timevec={poses.time}`. See [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html) for more on string arrays

Comment: What if `poses` is 2d?

Comment: @Eric the brackets `[...]` on `[poses.time]` will concatenate it in a 1D array, regardless of the size of `poses` (as long as the actual values cán be put in a 1D array). Use [reshape](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to get it back into the shape you started with

Comment: So in general, `reshape(mystruct.member, size(mystruct))`?

Comment: `reshape([mystruct.member], size(mystruct))` if `member` is a scalar

Answer (score 2):

For cases that the field values are vectors (of same size) and you need the result in a matrix form:

```
posmat = cell2mat({poses.pose}');
```

That returns each `pose` vector in a different row of `posmat`.