# How to convert a struct to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a 10 x 10 struct with four fields a,b,c,d.

How do I convert this struct to a 10 x 10 matrix with entries only from the field a?

Comment: Does the field contain only numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract field of struct array to new array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082746/extract-field-of-struct-array-to-new-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the fact that `str.a` returns a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). We can therefore concatenate the values together and reshape the resulting array to be the same size as the input struct.

```
% If a contains scalars
out = reshape([str.a], size(str));

% If a contains matrices
out = reshape({str.a}, size(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

**One liner solution**

```
res = cellfun(@(strctObj) strctObj.a,str,'UniformOutput',false);
```

**Further explanation**

Define a one-line function which extract the a value.

```
getAFunc = @(strctObj) strctObj.a;
```

use MATLAB's cellfun function to apply it on your cell and extract the matrix:

```
res = cellfun(@(strctObj) getAFunc ,strctCellObj,'UniformOutput',false);
```

**Example**

```
%initializes input
N=10;
str = cell(N,N);
for t=1:N*N
  str{t}.a = rand; 
  str{t}.b = rand; 
  str{t}.c = rand; 
  str{t}.d = rand; 
end
%extracts output matrix
res = cellfun(@(strctObj) strctObj.a,str,'UniformOutput',false);
```